# Convert of Data Type to factor

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a huge data set of 42 columns and 10k rows. I am trying to change my entire data frame (say data) into factor data type. But when I am using the code it is taking a long time to run. Is there any shortcut for the same?

```
as.factor(data)
```

I need a code that takes less time.

Comment: how did you read the data into R? On reading ensure to use the argument `colClasses="factor"` in that case all the columns will be factors. If you can run a faster loop, then `rapply(data,as.factor,how="replace")` should work

Comment: Or `data[] <- lapply(data, as.factor)`

Comment: I used 'data = read.csv("cleaned_data.csv")' to read data into R

Answer (score 0):

Do all 42 columns need to be formatted? If not, then you might want to consider indices:

```
as.factor(data[, x])
```

Where x represents the column number.

Comment: the second command is incorrect. You cannot run `as.factor()` on a list. Remember dataframe is a special list. Also if it were a matrix, the levels would cut across the columns and thus rendering it incorrect still

Comment: @Onyambu thank you. I have removed the second statement.

Answer (score 0):

```r
data[] <- lapply(data, factor)
```